# Apparently inconsistent reference behavior in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, reference

When referencing a given row from another one in a 2D numpy array, I noticed what to me looks like unexpected behavior

```
a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
a[1] = a[0]
a[1] += 100
```

After this operation, `a` will be equal to:

```
array([[  1,   2], [101, 102]])
```

I do not understand why the reference to `a[0]` is not considered and only `a[1]` is modified. Especially because with Python lists this is not the case:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
a[1] = a[0]
a[1][1] = 999
```

This will give `a`:

```
[[1, 999], [1, 999]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NumPy array of any not-`object` dtype does not contain references. So when you set `a[1] = a[0]` it just copies the content of `a[0]` into `a[1]`. That means that any subsequent assignments to `a[1]` or `a[0]` won't change the other one.

A list on the other hand doesn't copy when you have `a[1] = a[0]` it just inserts a reference to `a[0]` in `a[1]`. That means an assignment to either `a[1]` or `a[0]` will also change the other one.

The take-away is probably: Don't think of a NumPy array as containing references. It's actually not a nested "array" even if multidimensional. It's always a one-dimensional array that uses "strides" to "appear multidimensional".

---

It may help to compare "identities" here. That's a bit more complicated because NumPy doesn't work with references but works with a memory buffer. However NumPy provides a function to check for shared memory:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
>>> a[1] = a[0]
>>> np.shares_memory(a[1], a[0])  # the arrays don't share memory
False

>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> a[1] = a[0]
>>> a[1] is a[0]                  # they are the same object
True
```

Note that this is different if you just take a "view" of a NumPy array **without assigning it to an array**. The assignment to the NumPy array is what does the copy. That's because, like I said, NumPy arrays don't store references, it only stores elements. So you can have a view into an array but you can't insert a view *as view* into a NumPy array.

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = a[0]                      # b is now a view into "a"
>>> np.shares_memory(b, a[0])
True

>>> a[1] = b
>>> np.shares_memory(b, a[1])     # a[1] is not a view into "a[0]".
False
```

Comment: But where does the result of `a[1][1]=999` fit into this answer?  Can you clarify?

Comment: @saintsfan342000 I updated the answer. Let me know if it needs further elaboration.

Comment: Yes it does, and now I also realize that the main reason for my lack of clear understanding was that I had misread the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought your reasoning was rather clear to me. But then I tried the following   `>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = a[0]
>>> b[1] = 999
>>> a, b is a[0]
(array([[  1, 999],
       [  3,   4]]), False)`. So `b` and `a[0]` are not the same object, but if I modify `b` , then `a` also gets modified. Don't understand why

Comment: Ah, good example but actually not relevant here `a[0]` creates a `view`. If you operate with the view you will change both `b` and `a[0]`. In your case it's the assignment `a[1] = b` (for example) what does a copy. I updated the answer to clarify the point and actually provide a working method to check for "shared memory with NumPy arrays".

Comment: Now it's clear. Thank you. I was not aware of this method 'np.shares_memory' new in version 1.13 ; it helps understand the reason of my confusion